# .htaccess 301 redirects from ?url=[variable] to /[variable]/

Tags: .htaccess

How can I use .htaccess to 301 redirect from:
https://www.example.com/category/products.php?url=[variable]

To:
https://www.example.com/category/products/[variable]/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an error in my question because I'm not that familiar with mod_rewrite. I did not want to 301 redirect, I just needed to generate URL friendly page.

Below is an example of an ugly URL, friendly url and the RewriteRule. I hope it helps someone with the same question.

Ugly URL:
https://www.example.com/category/index.php?product=fireplace

Friendly URL:
https://www.example.com/category/fireplace

RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule  ^category/(.+)$  category/index.php?product=$1 [QSA,L]
```